# How to Increase Selenium Chrome Node Instances

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently trying to use selenium's chromedriver to launch some Node instance on an Amazon EC2 server for some testing. Ideally I want to reach a 1000+ node instance all running Chrome but that's where the problem begins.

After launching 84 node instances selenium refuses to launch any more nodes & I just get a timeout error.
I thought it may have been a ulimit issue but changing the ulimit -n did not make a difference.
I also tried setting this all up on new different EC2 instance but no luck here either.

I am using webdriverio's javascript bindings combined with selenium-standalone to run the chrome headless instances. 
RAM shouldnt be an issue since the EC2 servers I am using have 100gb+ RAM each.

Been dealing with this issue for around a week now so any advice would be helpful!!

Client side error:

```
 RuntimeError: RuntimeError
      (UnknownError:13) An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
 Problem: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.12.301324     (de8ab311bc9374d0ade71f7c167bad61848c7c48),
 platform=Linux 3.2.0-60-virtual x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any 
 stacktrace information)
 Command duration or timeout: 60.56 seconds
 Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
 System info: host: 'ip-172-31-25-40', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64',  
 os.version: '3.2.0-60-virtual', java.version: '1.7.0_65'
 Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

      Callstack:
      -> init()
```

Here is the full error output on the selenium server side:

```
20:32:19.818 WARN - Exception thrown java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:     
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-25-40', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64',         
os.version: '3.2.0-60-virtual', java.version: '1.7.0_65'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
.
.
.
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-25-40', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64',     
os.version: '3.2.0-60-virtual', java.version: '1.7.0_65'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(
DefaultDriverProvider.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(
DefaultDriverProvider.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(
DefaultDriverFactory.java:54)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:214)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:168)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor12.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(
DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(
DefaultDriverProvider.java:59)
... 9 more

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: 
exited  abnormally

(Driver info: chromedriver=2.12.301324 (de8ab311bc9374d0ade71f7c167bad61848c7c48),
platform=Linux 3.2.0-60-virtual x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any \
stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.54 seconds
```

Node instance code:

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome', 
        version: 38
    },
    port: 4444 // same port as the one used by the selenium-start server 
};


var url = "example.com";

var seconds = 3600;

webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .url(url)
    .pause(seconds * 1000)
    .end();
```

Comment: Can you post your code to start the Selenium instances?

Comment: I added it. I workaround I found was to just have an instance open up the same video multiple times. Not the best solution but for what I am doing, it'll do